# Add a text element using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying [lesson 1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23article-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fjetpack%2Fcompose%2Ftutorial)

However, the first step Add a text element is not working, i just get a blank screen.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Text("Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening, is that since you're not defining a theme to work with, the text color might be white, as well as the background.

If your background is white, try to replace

```
Text("Hello world!")
```

with

```
Text(text = "Hello world!", color = Color.Black)
```